# Checking a user's password in meteor JS

Tags: javascript, meteor

In my Meteor application I want to change another user's password. I would like to know if there is any way to get the old password before changing it.

This is my server side method:

```
 updateuser(id,password, options) {
    try {
        Meteor.users.update({ _id: id }, { $set: options })
        Accounts.setPassword(id, password, options)
    }
    catch (e) {
        return false;
        throw new Meteor.Error(500, 'updateUser error', e);
    }
}
```

I would like to know if the old password is correct or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot *get* the old password as it is hashed, but you can check whether or not it is correct if you have it in plaintext.

You can use the `Accounts._checkPassword(user, password)` methods in order to check if the old password is correct. It is implemented [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/accounts-password/password_server.js#L61).

`user` should be the user object and `password` should be the plain text password string.

If the result (which is an object) does not contain an `error` property, then the password is correct.

You can also take a look (for inspiration) at the [implementation](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/accounts-password/password_server.js#L416) of the method used for handling calls to [`Accounts.changePassword(oldPassword, newPassword, [callback])`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-changePassword), which changes the current user's password.

---

If you don't want to send the plain text password to the server (and it is generally better not to send the plain text version), you can hash it on the client using SHA256, by passing it to `Accounts._hashPassword(plainTextPassword)` (implemented [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/accounts-password/password_client.js#L75), in the `accounts-password` package).

```js
// on the client
>>> Accounts._hashPassword("foobar");

{
  "digest":"c3ab8ff13720e8ad9047dd39466b3c8974e592c2fa383d4a3960714caef0c4f2",
  "algorithm":"sha-256"
}
```

Call your server method with the results of this function. Assuming you have the SHA256 hashed password as `oldPassword` in your method:

```
//on the server
const user = Meteor.users.findOne(userId);
Accounts._checkPassword(user, "wrongPassword");
// results in:
{ userId: 'theuserid',
  error: 
   { [Error: Incorrect password [403]]
     error: 403,
     reason: 'Incorrect password',
     details: undefined,
     message: 'Incorrect password [403]',
     errorType: 'Meteor.Error' } }

Accounts._checkPassword(user, oldPassword);
// results in the following if the password is correct
{ userId: 'theuserid' }
```

Comment: Do you mean by "plainText" that the type of  password input should be "text " and not password ??

Comment: No, I mean that you need to have a string that contains the password, or an object that contains a sha-256 version of it (the result of hashing the password string via `SHA256(password)`).

Comment: Then shoud I add any specific package ??

Comment: Everything is implemented by the `accounts-password` package. I added a few details about hashing and checking the password. Anyway, you don't seem to pass the original password to the method anyway. What is its purpose? What is it that you are trying to achieve? Have you considered security?